# Resize the container from the right side, while the left side stays fixed in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, containers, resize

I have a container that currently resizes when being dragged from the bottom-right corner but it resizes symmetrically from both sides(right and left) I want the left side to stay where it is and when I am dragging the bottom-right corner it should resize to the bottom and right dimensions. How can I change the default origin of the container(center) to the top-left corner?

Here are my code snippets for that functionality:

```
var body: some View {
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.clear)
                            .frame(width: rectangleSize.width, height: rectangleSize.height)
                            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle().stroke())
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .position(x: rectangleSize.width, y: rectangleSize.height)
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        let newWidth = max(value.location.x, 15)
                                        let newHeight = max(value.location.y, 15)
                                        adjustContainerSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
                                    }
                            )
```

And the function for resizing:

```
private func adjustContainerSize(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        let maxX = verticalLines.last ?? 0
        let maxY = horizontalLines.last ?? 0
        let newWidth = max(width, maxX + 5)
        let newHeight = max(height, maxY + 5)
        rectangleSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        self.selectedId = self.id
    }
```

P.S. If you need more context feel free to point that out, I will add some.